# update a row in database sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

my friends, i have an issue about sql statement, i want to update a row with specific

parameters, when it is about one variable it is ok, but now i need to specify two.

HERE the code :

```
 public void insertMembre(long id,String rm_26ts, int a36, int a37_1, int a38_1_1,
        int a38_1_2, int a37_2, int a38_2_1, int a38_2_2){

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                    values.put(col_VUE,a37_1);
                    values.put(col_Vue_un ,a38_1_1);
                    values.put(col_Vue_deux, a38_1_2);

 db.update(Membres_de_Menage,values,col_N_Ordre+"="+rm_26ts +_idquest+"="+id,  null);
           }
```

i have error sql exception : unrecognized token

Comment: You should always use SQL parameters, like @krishna answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
db.update(Membres_de_Menage,values,col_N_Ordre+"='"+rm_26ts+"' AND " +_idquest+"="+id,  null);
```

instead of

```
db.update(Membres_de_Menage,values,col_N_Ordre+"="+rm_26ts +_idquest+"="+id,  null);
```

Comment: This is a bad solution! @krishna solution should be used!

Comment: @LS_dev : first of all, thanks for your concern and your contribution to resolve this issue, but when you speak about bad or good solution you should give arguments and explain why, also in my case the solution of krichna (my thanks to her)is not possible, i have multiple queries with the same structure that i wrote, so what i was looking for is how to adjust my queries not to start from the blank that's why Apporv solution is adapted to my situation. Thanks again for information

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

When you are checking more than one parameter then use "AND" or "OR" clause to join two or more conditions.

```
db.update(Membres_de_Menage,values,col_N_Ordre+"='"+rm_26ts +"' AND " +_idquest+"="+id,  null);
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: i appreciate your help, i will try it and tell you the results :)

Comment: This is a bad solution! @krishna solution should be used!

Comment: @LS_dev :: Both the solution works the same. so its up to the dev which solution to use.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger No doubt about it, but also I should keep him informed about bad practices. I really get pissed off when a see bad answers accepted against good ones. This forum is a reference in developer community, so we must try to get best quality possible!

Comment: @LS_dev : first of all, thanks for your concern and your contribution to resolve this issue, but when you speak about bad or good solution you should give arguments and explain why, also in my case the solution of krichna (my thanks to her)is not possible, i have multiple queries with the same structure that i wrote, so what i was looking for is how to adjust my queries not to start from the blank that's why Apporv solution is adapted to my situation. Thanks again for information

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
db.update(Membres_de_Menage, values, col_N_Ordre + " = ? AND " + _idquest + " = ?", new String[] {rm_26ts, id});
```